# CollapsingToolbarLayout is not working when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using android `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but it is not working for me.
I'm using it inside `AppBarLayout` and I also used `CoordinatorLayout` But still this is not working. Can you please let me know what I'm missing.
Here is my all code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <include
                layout="@layout/view_feed_toolbar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivUserProfile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_feed_top" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/AppBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvFeed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/feedLoading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/btn_fab_margins"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_top"
            app:backgroundTint="#fcfcfc"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            app:rippleColor="#ccc"
            android:onClick="onTakePhotoClick"/>

        <include layout="@layout/view_no_internet" />
        <include layout="@layout/view_no_feed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/view_bottom_navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Above is my all code that I'm using. There are some include layouts every layout is defined and working. What I'm missing ?

Comment: add screenshot from your result

Comment: You should go through one of these links to see how collapsing toolbar layout works. This links will be helpful to you to understand basic function of collapsing toolbar.

http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

or

https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/